# Docker compose ARGS not working with environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Am trying to understand the `args:` usage in the **docker-compose.yml** file so that I can set the environment variables during build run-time. I understood that, if I had a **.env** file then it automatically sets it and am able to access inside my **Dockerfile** like,

```
FROM node:alpine
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV} // --> This works fine if .env file is present
```

But if I want to load these values through `environment:` (in **docker-compose.yml** and no **.env** file) like,

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    image: web
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dev
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NODE_ENV
    ports:
      - 8100
```

then it returns a blank/empty value inside **Dockerfile**.

I found that the environment variables are not directly accessible inside Dockerfile (or during build) but how `env_file` works when hard-coding the environment variable does not.

Advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Docker version - in older versions of Docker **the Dockerfile ENV command uses a space instead of '='**

```
FROM node:alpine
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE_ENV}
```

Comment: According to the docs - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env, `ENV key=value` is equivalent to `ENV key value`. It's just supports multiple variables.

Comment: Yay, thanks for letting me know..... that is definitely new as I'm fairly sure it doesn't on older dockers and that it has bitten me in the past.